# Pygame Surface.fill() not working

Tags: python, pygame

I recently started learning pygame. I made a very basic program (all it does is change it's own background colour):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    DISPLAY.fill((3,4,5))
    pygame.display.update()
```

yet when the program ran all it did was produce a blank, black pygame window. I am using Windows 10 64-bit home with python 3.5.2 and pygame 1.9.1. Please help me figure out why the program didn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works fine, you're just using a very dark colour (R=3/255, G=4/255, B=5/255). Try this to get a blue screen:

```
DISPLAY.fill((0,0,255))
```

From the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) on `Surface.fill`:

> ```
> fill(color, rect=None, special_flags=0) -> Rect
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The color argument can be either a RGB sequence, a RGBA sequence or a mapped color index.

Each component of an RGB value ranges from 0 to 255, with 255 representing the maximum intensity of that component. Pure black would be represented as `(0, 0, 0)` and white as `(255, 255, 255)`.

---

For better demonstration (or fun), you can use this program to get an idea of what background colours you can get from different RGB values:

```
from itertools import product

import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))

for r, g, b in product(range(0, 255, 16), repeat=3):
    print('r={}, g={}, b={}'.format(r, g, b))
    DISPLAY.fill((r, g, b))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(10)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! Your answer fixed my problem!